# not deceting wireless NIC card but in widows its work fine

Tags: wireless, atheros

i have ubuntu 14.04 then upgrade to 15.04 afterthat my wireless  NIC card is not detecting but in windows 10 its working fine... and ubuntu 15.04 unable to detect it to work. how to solve that problem ..please suggest..
when put command on Terminal i.e iwconfig or any thing else only eth0 and lo are there no wlan0 or wlan1 etc ...what to do ..so that my wifi works fine...
Detail Description...after installing ubuntu 15.04 everything works fine except the wifi . Nither its detected nor its works to surf internet ..with LAN and Bluetooth its work fine only problem with wi-fi with Airplane mode on or off doesn't matter not working ..i have there are so many to complain about it also gave some suggesstion to the question but sorry to say its doesn't work... its my suggestion to the developer team to work for the WI-FI with advance driver to come

Comment: Let's start by identifying your wireless device. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`.  Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: ujjal@ujjal-Aspire-E5-573:~$ lspci -nm | grep 0280     :-----:                                           
03:00.0 "0280" "168c" "0042" -r30 "105b" "e09a"    .This the result of the command that u aks for now what ..

Comment: rfkill list all  command show this as follows :----:  jjal@ujjal-Aspire-E5-573:~$ rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
ujjal@ujjal-Aspire-E5-573:~$

Answer (score 0):

Your Atheros wireless device 168c:0042 is not yet supported in the Linux kernel. Please see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1484159

And also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2281584

From the last link:

> Finally, until support comes along, I'd suggest an inexpensive USB
>   wireless device. There are often threads here about working devices.

Comment: is there a way to download from Qualcom Atheros wirelesss driver for ubuntu 15.04 from Qualcom Atheros to install and make it work.there should be the other way...

Comment: There is no Ubuntu driver to download from Atheros or otherwise. Sorry.